# Angular JS and Dynamic Routing Issues

Tags: javascript, django, angularjs

I am trying to build a basic dynamic website using Django + AngularJS but I cant for the life of me seem to get dynamic routing working. My HTML is,

```
<html data-ng-app="homeApp">  
<body data-ng-app="homeController">   
<div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
    <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
         <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
             <li>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Home</a>
             </li>
             <li>
                <a href="#second"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i> second<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
    <div id="page-wrapper">
    <div data-ng-view></div>
</div>
```

And my Javascript file.

```
var homeApp = angular.module('homeApp', ['ngRoute']);
homeApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'home.html',
        controller: 'homeController'
    }).
      when('/second', {
        templateUrl: 'home.html',
        controller: 'testController'
      });
}]);
homeApp.controller('homeController', function($scope) {
});
homeApp.controller('testController', function($scope) {
});
```

But nothing loads when I click my navigation buttons

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell which browser you are using? This problem may occur in Chrome.
Your code might looks ok.

Remove ngRoute from following line.
var homeApp = angular.module('homeApp', []);

If you run this in firefox, Then your problem might be solved.
Thanks